# How to filter query result?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2

How would I filter out experiments that hasn't any associated circuit?

My Experiment model:

```
has_many :circuits
```

My query:

```
@experiments = Experiment.where(:public=>true).where(
        'updated_at >= :one_month_ago,
        :one_month_ago => Time.now - 30.days
    )
```

So, I need to avoid any experiment with circuits associated equal zero.
Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

> I need to avoid any experiment with circuits associated equal zero

One way is by setting a **`validation`** on your **`foreign_key(experiment_id)`** if you have it.

```
Class Circuit < ActiveRecord::Base

belongs_to :experiment

validates :experiment_id, :presence=>true 

end
```

So,by setting the above validation,you can make sure **`every circuit is associated to the expeiment`**.

Comment: But, how to exclude those experiments from query that had zero associated circuits?

Comment: @simo You no need to query for zero associated circuits.When this validation is given,there will not be any circuit which is not associated to experiment.It takes care of that.

Comment: It didn't work, see here http://dcaclab.com/en/users_experiments , the experiment "Series Circuit Practice" should not be listed, as it has zero circuits